# How to solve date issue while plotting using date_break command for the x axis level?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

This is the head of my data and code I am using.While ploting I got
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only. How to get rid of this?

```
> my_data
# A tibble: 3,722 x 19
   Year20              Year19              Year18              Year17              Year16              Year15             
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2020-03-01 00:00:00 2019-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00 2016-03-01 00:00:00 2015-03-02 00:00:00
 2 2020-03-01 00:00:00 2019-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00 2016-03-01 00:00:00 2015-03-03 00:00:00
 3 2020-03-01 00:00:00 2019-03-01 00:00:00 2018-03-01 00:00:00 2017-03-01 00:00:00 2016-03-01 00:00:00 2015-03-03 00:00:00

my_data <- read_excel("chhotanagpur.xlsx", sheet = "chhotanagpur")
my_data
my_data = as.data.frame(my_data)
f20 = as.data.frame(table(my_data$Year20))
f20$Var1 = as.Date(f20$Var1, "%Y-%m-%d")
f20$Var1 = format(f20$Var1, format="%m-%d")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)
g <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = f20, aes(x=Var1, y=cumsum(Freq), group = 1, color = "#111111"), size = 1) +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Cum_Freq')+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="3 day", date_labels = "%d/%m")
plot(g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `format` function returns a string not a date object, which is why the `scale_x_date` can't deal with it. If you run `str` on your dataframe you can see the data type of each column. As an example, the first attempt to graph below will work, but the second will fail:

```
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(rep(Sys.time(), 10))) %>%
  mutate(date2 = format(date, format = "%m-%d"))

str(df)

'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date : Date, format: "2020-07-23" "2020-07-23" "2020-07-23" "2020-07-23" ...
 $ date2: chr  "07-23" "07-23" "07-23" "07-23" ...
  
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(date)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_date()

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(date2)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_date()
```